# Loading lines of plain text values into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, text, web-scraping

I have lines of data that look like this:

```
+1
-1
+10
-56
```

How can I load these into a javascript array like below:

```
["+1","-1","+10","-56"]
```

without hand coding it line by line? I have a file with a thousand or so of these lines and am looking to do it quickly and reproducibly.

Thanks.

Comment: is `+1 -1 +10 -56`  this is string or what ?

Comment: Post sample data from actual file.

Comment: It's not a string. I want it to be a string. It's literally just a plain .txt file with +X or -Y on each line, continuing for a thousand or so lines

Answer (score 0):

You `split()`

**Since each of match you want is separated by space so you can simply split it by space character.**

```js
let str =  "+1 -1 +10 -56"
let op = str.split(' ');
console.log(op);
```

**You can do it with regex also. but in this case don't use regex. just for showing you more ways i am adding regex solution too.**

```js
let str =  "+1 -1 +10 -56"
let op = str.match(/[^ ]+/g);
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to load a text file into your app?

```js
function readSingleFile(evt) {
  const f = evt.target.files[0];
  if (f) {
    const r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = e => { 
      const contents = e.target.result;
      console.log(contents.split('\n'));
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
  } else {
    alert("Failed to load file");
  }
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```